# change size of split image

Tags: java, loops, nest

How can I change size of split image so it fix on screen?

Below, I am setting up two textureRegion. 1st will have the full image and 2nd will have the split image.

```
public TextureRegion fullImage;       //load a image
private TextureRegion[][] splitImage; //split image in 2d array


splitImage= fullImage.split(tileWidth, tileHeight);
```

this render a image but the size too big.

```
for (int row = 0; row < splitImage.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < splitImage[0].length; col++) {
            sb.draw(splitImage[row][col],
                    col * tileWidth, 
                    (Constants.ANDROID_HEIGHT - tileHeight) - (row * tileHeight));
        }
    }
```

how can I change width of each splitImage so it fit on screen?

Comment: What is your programming language?

Comment: my programming language is java

Comment: You should add java tag to your question.